# Create Set of Every Permutation and Sign Variation of Members of a Set (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, set

Suppose I am given a vector of unknown size.  For example, it could be

`std::vector<int> myset1({1, 2, 3});`

Or it could be anything else.  That's just an example.  Now, suppose I want to write a function that returns a vector of vectors.  However, each vector in this vector must be distinct permutations of the original.  So in this case, I would expect the function to return a vector containing the sets {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, and {3, 2, 1} (pay no attention to the ordering).

That might be straightforward with some kind of recursion.  But what if I also wanted to also account for the sign of each element?  So for example:

`std::vector<int> myset2({1, 2});`

I would expect the function to return {1, 2}, {1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, -2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1} (I'm not concerned with the ordering).

I'm struggling to think of a way to design this elegantly.  As you can imagine, with larger sets, it becomes a necessity to use such a function rather than to list out each set by hand, but no ideas are coming to my head at the moment.  How would you achieve this?

Comment: std::next_permuation() ?

Answer (score 3):

First attempt:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> all_permutations(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;

    std::sort(begin(input), end(input));
    input.erase(std::unique(begin(input), end(input)), end(input));
    do {
        result.push_back(input);
    } while(std::next_permutation(begin(input), end(input)));

    return result;
}

template<class T>
void emit(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "  [";
    const char* sep = " ";
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        os << sep << x;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << "]\n";
}

template<class T>
void emit(std::ostream& os, std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& v)
{
    os << "[\n";
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        emit(os, x);
    }
    os << "]\n";
}

int main()
{
    emit(std::cout, all_permutations({ 1, 2, 3 }));
}
```

expected output;

```
[
  [ 1, 2, 3]
  [ 1, 3, 2]
  [ 2, 1, 3]
  [ 2, 3, 1]
  [ 3, 1, 2]
  [ 3, 2, 1]
]
```

Now add code for plus and minus:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> all_permutations(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;

    std::sort(begin(input), end(input));
    input.erase(std::unique(begin(input), end(input)), end(input));
    do {
        result.push_back(input);
    } while(std::next_permutation(begin(input), end(input)));

    return result;
}

template<class T>
void emit(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "  [";
    const char* sep = " ";
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        os << sep << x;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << "]\n";
}

template<class T>
void emit(std::ostream& os, std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& v)
{
    os << "[\n";
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        emit(os, x);
    }
    os << "]\n";
}

std::vector<int> plus_and_minus(std::vector<int> v)
{
    std::vector<int> inverse;
    inverse.reserve(v.size());
    std::transform(begin(v), end(v), back_inserter(inverse), [](auto&& x) { return -x; });
    v.insert(end(v), begin(inverse), end(inverse));
    sort(begin(v), end(v));
    inverse.erase(unique(begin(v), end(v)), end(v));
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    emit(std::cout, all_permutations(plus_and_minus({ 1, 2, 3 })));
}
```

expected:

```
[
  [ -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
  [ -3, -2, -1, 1, 3, 2]
  [ -3, -2, -1, 2, 1, 3]
  [ -3, -2, -1, 2, 3, 1]
  [ -3, -2, -1, 3, 1, 2]
  [ -3, -2, -1, 3, 2, 1]
  [ -3, -2, 1, -1, 2, 3]
  [ -3, -2, 1, -1, 3, 2]
  [ -3, -2, 1, 2, -1, 3]
  [ -3, -2, 1, 2, 3, -1]
  [ -3, -2, 1, 3, -1, 2]
  [ -3, -2, 1, 3, 2, -1]
  [ -3, -2, 2, -1, 1, 3]
  [ -3, -2, 2, -1, 3, 1]
  [ -3, -2, 2, 1, -1, 3]
  [ -3, -2, 2, 1, 3, -1]
  [ -3, -2, 2, 3, -1, 1]
  [ -3, -2, 2, 3, 1, -1]
  [ -3, -2, 3, -1, 1, 2]
  [ -3, -2, 3, -1, 2, 1]
  [ -3, -2, 3, 1, -1, 2]
  [ -3, -2, 3, 1, 2, -1]
  [ -3, -2, 3, 2, -1, 1]
  [ -3, -2, 3, 2, 1, -1]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 1, 2, 3]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 1, 3, 2]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 2, 1, 3]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 2, 3, 1]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 3, 1, 2]
  [ -3, -1, -2, 3, 2, 1]
  [ -3, -1, 1, -2, 2, 3]
  [ -3, -1, 1, -2, 3, 2]
  [ -3, -1, 1, 2, -2, 3]
  [ -3, -1, 1, 2, 3, -2]
  [ -3, -1, 1, 3, -2, 2]
  [ -3, -1, 1, 3, 2, -2]
  [ -3, -1, 2, -2, 1, 3]
  [ -3, -1, 2, -2, 3, 1]
  [ -3, -1, 2, 1, -2, 3]
  [ -3, -1, 2, 1, 3, -2]
  [ -3, -1, 2, 3, -2, 1]
  [ -3, -1, 2, 3, 1, -2]
  [ -3, -1, 3, -2, 1, 2]
  [ -3, -1, 3, -2, 2, 1]
  [ -3, -1, 3, 1, -2, 2]
  [ -3, -1, 3, 1, 2, -2]
  [ -3, -1, 3, 2, -2, 1]
  [ -3, -1, 3, 2, 1, -2]
  [ -3, 1, -2, -1, 2, 3]
  [ -3, 1, -2, -1, 3, 2]
  [ -3, 1, -2, 2, -1, 3]
  [ -3, 1, -2, 2, 3, -1]
  [ -3, 1, -2, 3, -1, 2]
  [ -3, 1, -2, 3, 2, -1]
  [ -3, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3]
  [ -3, 1, -1, -2, 3, 2]
  [ -3, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3]
  [ -3, 1, -1, 2, 3, -2]
  [ -3, 1, -1, 3, -2, 2]
  [ -3, 1, -1, 3, 2, -2]
  [ -3, 1, 2, -2, -1, 3]
  [ -3, 1, 2, -2, 3, -1]
  [ -3, 1, 2, -1, -2, 3]
  [ -3, 1, 2, -1, 3, -2]
  [ -3, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1]
  [ -3, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2]
  [ -3, 1, 3, -2, -1, 2]
  [ -3, 1, 3, -2, 2, -1]
  [ -3, 1, 3, -1, -2, 2]
  [ -3, 1, 3, -1, 2, -2]
  [ -3, 1, 3, 2, -2, -1]
  [ -3, 1, 3, 2, -1, -2]
  [ -3, 2, -2, -1, 1, 3]
  [ -3, 2, -2, -1, 3, 1]
  [ -3, 2, -2, 1, -1, 3]
  [ -3, 2, -2, 1, 3, -1]
  [ -3, 2, -2, 3, -1, 1]
  [ -3, 2, -2, 3, 1, -1]
  [ -3, 2, -1, -2, 1, 3]
  [ -3, 2, -1, -2, 3, 1]
  [ -3, 2, -1, 1, -2, 3]
  ...etc
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82a4c5784dc0070d

Answer (score 2):

Just for exposition, another way. This time using a generator object which offers an iterator-based approach.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ciso646>

template<class Vector> struct permutation_engine;

template<class T>
struct permutation_engine<std::vector<T>>
{
    using perm_vector = std::vector<T>;

    template<class VectorArg>
    permutation_engine(VectorArg&& arg) : current_permutation(std::forward<VectorArg>(arg)) {}

    struct iterator
    {
        using value_type = const perm_vector;
        using reference = perm_vector&;
        using pointer = perm_vector*;
        using difference_type = int;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        reference operator*() const { return parent->current_permutation; }
        auto operator != (iterator const& r) const -> bool {
            return parent != r.parent;
        }

        auto operator++() { 
            if(not parent->advance()) {
                parent = nullptr;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        permutation_engine* parent;
    };

    iterator begin() 
    {
        reset();
        return iterator { this };
    }
    iterator end() { return iterator { nullptr }; }    

    bool advance() {
        return next_permutation(Begin(), End());
    }

    void reset() {
        sort(Begin(), End());
        current_permutation.erase(unique(Begin(), End()), End()); 
    }

    private:
        auto Begin() { return std::begin(current_permutation); }
        auto End() { return std::end(current_permutation); }


    std::vector<T> current_permutation;
};

template<class Vector>
auto make_permutation_engine(Vector&& vector)
{
    return permutation_engine<std::decay_t<Vector>>(std::forward<Vector>(vector));
}

template<class T>
void emit(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "  [";
    const char* sep = " ";
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        os << sep << x;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << "]\n";
}

std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v)
{
    using negateElement = std::negate<>;

    v.reserve(v.size() * 2);
    std::transform(begin(v), end(v), 
                   back_inserter(v), 
                   negateElement());

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "[\n";
    for(auto&& vec : make_permutation_engine(append_negatives({ 1, 2, 3 })))
    {
        emit(std::cout, vec);
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```